# Searching a list for the longest string

Tags: python, list, search, max

I have a list which is generated when a user inputs a string: like this. It will take each individual word and append it to a list.

I have a variable called max_l which finds the length of the longest string in the list.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
while max_l == len(mylist[x]):
    print(mylist[x])
    a=a+1
```

So, it's meant to go through the list and compare each item with the integer max_l. Once it finds that list item, it's meant to print it. It doesn't though. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do here, but the length of the longest can just be found with `max(mylist, key=len)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to search a list for the longest string you could use the builtin `max()` function:

```
myList = ['string', 'cat', 'mouse', 'gradient']

print max(myList, key=len)
'gradient'
```

`max` takes a 'key' argument to which you can assign a function(in this case `len`, another builtin function) which is applied to each item in myList.

In this case whichever `len(string)` for each string in `myList` returns the largest outcome(length) is your longest string, and is returned by `max`.

**From the `max` docstring:**

```
max(iterable[, key=func]) -> value
max(a, b, c, ...[, key=func]) -> value

With a single iterable argument, return its largest item.
With two or more arguments, return the largest argument.
```

**From the `len` docstring:**

```
len(object) -> integer

Return the number of items of a sequence or mapping.
```

**Generating list from user input:**

In response to your comment, I thought I would add this. This is one way to do it:

```
user = raw_input("Enter a string: ").split() # with python3.x you'd be using input instead of raw_input

Enter a string: Hello there sir and madam # user enters this string
print user
['Hello', 'there', 'sir', 'and', 'madam']
```

now to use max:

```
print max(user, key=len)
'Hello' # since 'Hello' and 'madam' are both of length 5, max just returns the first one
```

Comment: I feel kind of stupid. I tried this but it was returning weird values.

Comment: If you have a list of strings like the one I used above, this should work normally. How are you generating your list exactly? Also, what kind of weird values? Please see my edit

Comment: If it still doesn't work, please let me know and perhaps post the output your getting either in the comments here(if it's not too long) or at the end of your original post.