# Print the word (from user input) with the max amount of characters python

Tags: python, list, split, char, max

so the objective of this exercise is simple but I'm stuck. The program should take a list from user input (eg. tomatoes, fish, milk, watermelons...) and print the longest word in the list. So far I'm only able to print the amount of characters in the longest word.

```
    user_input=input("Type a list of words separated by spaces ") 
    string_words=user_input
    words= string_words.split()

    maximum_char = max(len(w)for w in words)
    print("The longest word in the list has",maximum_char, "characters")

    if len(words) == maximum_char:
       print(words)
```

Comment: You need to loop through `words` to find a word whose length is `maximum_char`. In your comparison, len(words) is *not* what you want: it's the number of words entered. Another problem: if the words entered are to be separated by commas, then you need to use `.split(',') and then use `len(w.strip())` to get rid of whitespace when evaluating `max`. Either that, or just enter the words separated by spaces.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Searching a list for the longest string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618815/searching-a-list-for-the-longest-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `key` argument for the `max()` function:

```
max_word = max(words, key=len)
print('The longest word in the list is "{}" at {} characters.'.format(max_word, len(max_word)))
```

This key means that `max()` will determine the "maximum" word based on whatever is returned for that word by the key function, which is `len` in this case.

Comment: Thank you! That worked nicely. I've gone over dictionaries, keys, and values. I just didn't know how to implement what I had learned.

Comment: Cool way to do it: +1 for `max` with `key`